# Sed: Delete all characters before double dash, including the double dash

Tags: sed

I have a list of file names that have double dashes:

```
New York--1984 and counting.txt
Timeless Wonders--Silver-Guardians.txt
Project Blue Gale--Hills of Green.txt
```

I need remove the double dashes and all characters before the double dash:

```
1984 and counting.txt
Silver-Guardians.txt
Hills of Green.txt
```

Here is mode code using SED:

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$(sed 's/[^\--]*--//')"; done
```

> RE error: invalid character range

If I change it, so it only searches for a single dash, it works. So how I can search for a double dash? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe `"$(sed 's/^[^-]*--//' <<< "$f")"` will do?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that works, the full command I used was `for f in *; do mv "$f" "$(sed 's/^[^-]*--//' <<< "$f")"; done`. Please post as an answer, so I can mark as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the fact your `[^\--]` pattern defines a range between `\` (dec. 92) and `-` (dec. 45), which is incorrect.

I suggest using

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "$(sed 's/^[^-]*--//' <<< "$f")"; done
```

The `sed 's/^[^-]*--//'` command will remove all 0 or more chars other than `-` from the start of the string till the `--` substring.

Or, you may use parameter expansion, `${f#*--}` (as [indicated by @tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59878556/sed-delete-all-characters-before-double-dash-including-the-double-dash/59878680?noredirect=1#comment105886842_59878680)). It will remove 0 or more chars from the start of the string as few as possible (`#*`) up to the first `--`.

See [online demo](https://ideone.com/8xHXGN):

```
s="New York--1984 and counting.txt"
echo "${s#*--}";
sed 's/^[^-]*--//' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
1984 and counting.txt
1984 and counting.txt
```

Comment: Of course, the shell offers parameter expansions which should be significantly more effiicient: `mv "$f" "${f#*--}"` (though you need to add a separate guard to prevent a dash before the double dash if that is something you want to prevent).

Comment: @tripleee Yes, used this one yesterday in my script, but I focused on the regex approach here

Comment: `[^-]*` will fail to catch `New-York--` - just assuming that a single dash / minus can appear in the text to be removed. `.*?` would cover that situation also.

Comment: @virolino `sed` does not support lazy quantifiers. Parameter expansion is more likely to work here.

Comment: @virolino Most `sed` dialects do not support non-greedy matching. But the OP specifically seems to want to avoid anything with a dash anyway.

Comment: Oh, I am not that familiar with the limitations of `sed`, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
parallel --dryrun mv {} {= s/.*?--// =} ::: *.txt
```

Run the command in the directory with the source files and inspect the output. If all checks out, remove the `--dryrun` option and run again.

An alternative solution using  GNU sed:

```
ls *.txt | sed -E 'h;s/--/\n/;H;g;s/(.*)\n.*\n(.*)/mv -v "\1" "\2"/e'
```

N.B. Remove the `e` substitution flag if you want to check before you run for real.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with the [`rename` tool](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/File-Rename/rename.PL) (the Perl one, not the util-linux one):

```
$ rename -n 's/.*?--//' *.txt
'New York--1984 and counting.txt' would be renamed to '1984 and counting.txt'
'Project Blue Gale--Hills of Green.txt' would be renamed to 'Hills of Green.txt'
'Timeless Wonders--Silver-Guardians.txt' would be renamed to 'Silver-Guardians.txt'
```

Removing the `-n` actually performs the renaming. `.*?--` is a regular expression to non-greedily match everything up to the first occurrence of `--`.